# Issue converting excel to csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have an excel file which has text column containing data in the format **(1) (2)**.

But when i save it as csv file it shows me as **-1,-2** in both excel and sublime text editor.

If i modify the csv in excel by adding () to numbers. For e.g **(1)**. It shows me **-1** in excel but now **(1)** in sublime text editor.

If i add some more columns to csv file in excel then after saving the file, the numbers are again changed from **(1)** to **-1** in both excel and sublime text editor.

Ideally numbers should be displayed as **(1)** in csv file whether loaded in excel or sublime text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending a ' before the actual numbers.

Excel, by default treats numbers in braces as negative numbers.

For example, '(1) will be saved in Excel as (1) in the cell, with formatting saved as Text.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i have already added '(1) in excel. When i save it as csv file and load in excel it shows -1 but in text editor for e.g. sublime text it shows (1) which is correct. The problem comes when we make any changes in the existing csv file. The (1) which was correctly shown in sublime text now shows as -1.